# odoo how to update the value of one field by updating the value of other, both field is in different class

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-9

I am very new to odoo, I want to update the value of `discount_type` and `discount` as I update or change the value of `global_discount_type` and `global_order_discount`.How can I achieve this as both variables are from different class. I am unable to do using general python approach.
Please guide me.

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
_inherit = "purchase.order"

  total_discount = fields.Monetary(string='Total Discount', store=True, readonly=True, compute='_amount_all',
                                 track_visibility='always')
global_discount_type = fields.Selection([
    ('fixed', 'Fixed'),
    ('percent', 'Percent')
], string="Discount Type", )
global_order_discount = fields.Float(string='Global Discount', store=True, track_visibility='always')

class PurchaseOrderLine(models.Model):
_inherit = "purchase.order.line"

discount = fields.Float(string='Discount', digits=dp.get_precision('Discount'), default=0.0)
discount_type = fields.Selection([
    ('fixed', 'Fixed'),
    ('percent', 'Percent')
], string="Discount Type", default='percent')
```

Do I need to made changes in xml file also?
I want to achieve this using onchange.

Comment: should `global_discount_type` and `global_order_discount` change for each line ?

Comment: Do you need mixed discounts/-type? Or should every order line always have the same discount and type like the order? Letter one could be done by using related fields on the lines. Or try to use on_change behaviour on the order and change all line values within it.

Comment: @CZoellner I want the same `discount_type` and `discount` to be applied on each item in the `purchase_order_line` and these `discount_type ` and `discount` should be same as the `global_discount_type` and `global_order_discount`. Like as I changes the value of `global_order_discount` and `global_discount_type` these changes should reflect in each column (means on each product individually).

Comment: @WaKo yes I want the changes to be reflect on each item instead of applying `global_discoun` on whole stock.

Comment: @Infinity You need to use related fields.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use use related fields and relate `discount_type` and `discount` on `purchase.order.line` to the `purchase.order`.

For example:

```
discount = fields.Float(related="order_id.global_order_discount")
```

Update `discount` and `discount_type` for each line when `global_order_discount` and `global_discount_type` respectively:

```
@api.onchange('global_order_discount', 'global_discount_type')
def onchange_field(self):
    for line in self.order_line:
        line.discount = self.global_order_discount
        line.discount_type = self.global_discount_type
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. I have methods for calculating 'total_discount' and its working fine. I want to reflect change in 'discount' and 'discount_type' as I changes the value 'global_discount_type' and 'global_discount'. These changes should appear on ui as well as back end. Thank you for look into this.

Comment: Thanks WaKo, This is what I needed.\n Please look into my comment on @CZoellner answer. I want to achieve some other things. Please look into this.

Comment: I don't know I am writing function right or not?There is no effect . Can you help me? Where should I define that function?

Comment: Add it in 'purchase.ordre' if 'global_discount_type' change update 'discount_type' for each line.

Comment: `@api.depends('product_qty', 'price_unit', 'taxes_id', 'discount', 'discount_type')
    def onchange_field(self):
        vals = {}
        if discount == True:
            vals['discount'] = PurchaseOrder.bulk_discount
            vals['discount_type'] = PurchaseOrder.bulk_discount_type
        return {value}`   Is this the right way?

Comment: Sorry,Actually its `global` in place of `bulk`.

Comment: For onchange method you need to use @api.onchange('global_discount_type', 'global_order_discount')

Comment: does @api.onchange also reflect changes on database?

Comment: No, just on UI.

Comment: can You elaborate how can I do this? Because I am getting error while implementing this.here is the demo  `@api.onchange('global_order_discount', 'global_discount_type', 'PurchaseOrderLine.discount',
                  'PurchaseOrderLine.discount_type')
    def onchange_field(self, cr, uid, ids, global_order_discount, global_discount_type, context=None): ` and in xml I have implemented this `onchange="onchange_field(bulk_discount_type,bulk_discount,context)` but getting the error TypeError: onchange_field() takes at least 6 arguments (5 given).Help me out

Comment: You do not need to define `onchange` in the XML view.Odoo will call `onchange_field` automaticaly when a field specified in the decorator has changed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have removed the `onchange` from the xml. but still getting the error. TypeError: onchange_field() takes at least 5 arguments (5 given)

Comment: Onchange takes only self as argument and it it one record.replace your method shown in comment with mine.I tested it and it works.

Comment: Thanks brother, It worked. I was working for days. Thanks again mate.:)

Answer (score 0):

This exemple may help,

We use depends in your case (Different model), defining all fields have relation with results
and we use onchange in the case of Same model.

```
@api.depends('order_id.total_discount', 'order_id.global_order_discount')
def _amount_all(self):
    for line in self:
        if line.order_id.total_discount == 'something' :
            line.discount_type = 'somethong1'
            line.discount = 'somethong2'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the global values reflect to the lines use related fields:

```py
class PurchaseOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = "purchase.order.line"

    discount = fields.Float(
        related="order_id.global_discount", string="Discount")
    discount_type = fields.Selection(
        related="order_id.global_discount_type", string="Discount Type")
```

Comment: Thanks @CZoellner it worked. Is there any method by which I can update `discount_type` and `discount` of individual purchase order line even after applying `global_discount_type` and `global_order_discount`. Here I am able to change globally only but I can't apply change on individual item as it automatically takes the global value. Thanks again, I just needed a single line.

Comment: That is the big disadvantage of this method.

Comment: Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Onchange could be a nice try

Comment: I think so. Let me do this and I ll tell you @CZoellner

Comment: help me write the onchange function. I am unable to get there.